# Can I have a rails 7 crud app with javascript and react without webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I have both javascript and react working in a rails 7 app using esbuild I've been using `--loader .js=jsx` which disables my javascript files ending in js (I assume, because they don't get output to the app/assets/builds folder which is what esbuild is supposed to do)

I had this app working with rails 6 and webpacker before I upgraded it to rails 7